# How to improve java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream performance to unzip a large .gz file?

Tags: java, compression, hdfs, gzipinputstream

I'm trying to unzip a very large .gz file in java around 50MB and then transferring it to hadoop file system. After unzipping, the file size becomes 20 GB. It takes more than 5 min to do this job.

```
protected void write(BufferedInputStream bis, Path outputPath, FileSystem hdfs) throws IOException 
{
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(hdfs.create(outputPath));
        IOUtils.copyBytes(bis, bos, 8*1024);
}
```

Even after using Buffered I/O streams, it is taking very long to decompress and transfer the file.

Does Hadoop is causing file transfer to be slow or GZIPInputStream is slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing 20 Gb *will* take time.  If you do it in 300 seconds you still write more than 70 Mb a second.

You may simply hit the limit of the platform.

If you rewrite your processing code to read the compressesed file that may help.

Comment: Using zcat command in linux i can accomplish this in 10 to 15 sec. That's why I wanted a faster way to decompress the file in java.

Comment: Your local linux machine most likely has a faster harddisk.

Comment: I'm using the same machine for both operations

Comment: You may want to do an benchmark experiment with a program creating a 20 Gb file of random data to hadoop fs.  This will show you the upper limit of your Hadoop system.